# Can a class which implements an interface be declared as interface in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I know that a class which implements an interface can be declared a abstract but not sure if it can be declared as interface? If so,What will be its benefit?

Comment: You can't have an interface implement an interface.  You *can* extend interfaces, though.

Comment: If it's a class, it's not an interface. If it's an interface, it's not a class.

Comment: You have two misconceptions. The first is that 'interface' is a modifier to classes; it is not because interfaces are not classes. The second is that interfaces can implement other interfaces; they cannot. If you wish to create a class which implements the properties of several interfaces, you can simply use commas and declare multiple interfaces to implement. Example: `class Dog implements Barker, Fetcher, Runner { //class def }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `interface` can **implement** an `interface` by definition.

An `interface` is a contract that formalizes a behavior and cannot **implement** logic.

However, interfaces can **extend** other interfaces.

An `abstract` class can implement an `interface` on the other hand, because either:

- Behavior is implemented in the `abstract` class, or
- Behavior implementation is deferred to classes extending the `abstract` class

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html)'s a general link to Oracle's OOP documentation you want to have a look at.